# local variable 'comment_form' referenced before assignment in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I created an app where user can login and post a contents he want, and now I decided to add comment section to each post user did in the app, I followed the tutorial in djangocentral website, but it's not working after I added everything into my app, when I click on (Read more), it's throw me an error in the browser: `local variable 'comment_form' referenced before assignment` if I deleted the `comment_form` inside the context of my viewPhoto view its shows nothing in viewPhoto template.

the model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80) 
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Photo, Category, Comment

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Photo)
@admin.register(Comment)

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'body', 'post', 'created_on', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created_on')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
    actions = ['approve_cooments']


    def approve_comment(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)
```

the form.py:

```
from dataclasses import fields
from pyexpat import model
from .models import Comment
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body',)
```

the view.py:

```
def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    template_name = 'photo.html'
    comment = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None


    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)

            new_comment.post = post

            new_comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post, 
    'comment':comment, 
    'new_comment': new_comment,
    'comment_form': comment_form})
```

viewPhoto template:

```
<body class="m-5">
<div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col">
               <div style="height: 90vh;">
                  <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="">

                  <p>{{post.description}}</p>
                  <p>{{post.user.username.upper}}</p>
                  <p>{{post.date_added}}</p>

               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
      {% for comment in comments %}
      <p>{{ comment.name }}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{{ comment.created_on }}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
 </div>


<div class="container">
     {% if new_comments %}
     <p>wait your comments is ready</p>

     <form method="POST"> 
          {% csrf_token %}             
          {{ comment_form.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
     </form>
     {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` should bind with the `if request.method == 'POST'` check, not with the `if comment_form.is_valid()` check, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    template_name = 'photo.html'
    comment = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None


    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post = post
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post, 
    'comment':comment, 
    'new_comment': new_comment,
    'comment_form': comment_form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: After I add this to my view actually it's not working, then I created a comments view in the view.py file and copy the code and paste it in new comments view, it's redirect me to the add comment templates but when I add new comments it's working fine and its added in admin, but the comments is not showing in the viewphoto templates, how can I solve that ?

Comment: The viewphoto template is not showing user comments

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: the default for `active` is `False`, but your `comment = ...` only retrieves comments with `active=True`...

Comment: So, what should I do now sir ? Where do I needs to change

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: that depends on the business logic you want to implement. If you want to show the comment added without activating it, you set `default=True` for the `active` field.

Comment: But when you look at my admin.py, and view.py the: active=True. I want the user comments to be shown in the post sir. If that isn't show in the post that Comment model is not important in the app.

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: well then likely the rendering logic for the comments does not work

Comment: Yes, and what are the solution for this sir.

Comment: Mr. Willem Van Onsem, Thank you so much and I love the way you are teaching people how to code the problem of comments not display in my app is because I didn't delete the images I added in my admin, your answer is the one that solve my problem. Thank you so much. You are my Guru.